# Taking in a URL as a command line argument, I get a "socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known" error

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a directory brute forcing tool (still relatively new to programming). I take a URL and a wordlist as command line arguments, however when I run this code:

```
import sys
import socket
import requests as req

rhost = sys.argv[1]
wordlist = sys.argv[2]

def parse_wordlist(wordlist):
    with open(wordlist, encoding="ISO-8859-1") as file:
        directories = file.read().strip().split("\n")
    return directories

directories = parse_wordlist(wordlist)

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((rhost, 80))
for directory in directories:
    status = req.get(f"{rhost}/{directory}").status_code
    if status == 200:
        print(f"Directory found: {rhost}/{directory}")
s.close()

print("Scan complete")
```

I get the following error: socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

As I was trying to find information on this most of the answers I found talked about localhost, and I don't think that applies to me (though I could be totally wrong). Also, I couldn't find any that addressed having the host URL variable defined from the command line.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm using Mac OS Mojave 10.14, I've seen that this is a problem mainly associated with Macs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to open `socket`. `req.get` will give you what you want.
You can enhance your code with `try except`:

```
import sys
import requests as req

rhost = sys.argv[1]
wordlist = sys.argv[2]

def parse_wordlist(wordlist):
    with open(wordlist, encoding="ISO-8859-1") as file:
        directories = file.read().strip().split("\n")
    return directories

directories = parse_wordlist(wordlist)

for directory in directories:
    try:
        status = req.get(f"{rhost}/{directory}").status_code
        if status == 200:
            print(f"Directory found: {rhost}/{directory}")
    except:
        continue

print("Scan complete")
```